# Difference between Button.onClickListener and View.onClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have seen people used View.onClickListener and Thenewboston in his tutorial he used Button.onClickListener for the setOnClickListener() method.So I just have a quick question- What is the difference between new Button.onClickListener() and View.onClickListener?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

`Button` does not have a `public static` interface named `OnClickListener`. However, `Button` inherits from `View`, and `View` has a `public static` interface named `OnClickListener`. Courtesy of inheritance, `Button` inherits that `OnClickListener` interface. Hence, either syntax will work.

On the whole, in Android, you will tend to see `View.OnClickListener`, to the point where I cannot remember the last time I saw someone reference `Button.OnClickListener` (or any other subclass of `View`, for that matter).